# Second fundamental form of an implicit surface

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm interested in expressions for the second fundamental form of an implicit surface $f(x,y,z) = 0$, in terms of the first and second derivatives $f_x, \ldots, f_{yz}$. I am not looking for the expressions of a function in Monge form, $z = h(x,y)$. That is I don't want to assume that I can rewrite the expression locally in the form. I have access only to $f$ and its derivatives. As a concrete example, suppose I have a function $x^2+y^2+z^2 - 1 = 0$, and I want to compute the coefficients of the second fundamental form $L, M, N$ in terms of the available derivatives, without rewriting $f$ in parts such as $z = \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$.

Comment: In [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222582448_Curvature_formulas_for_implicit_curves_and_surfaces) there are some formulas for the curvature of curves and surfaces given in implicit form. Maybe it has what you're looking for too.